# Uncountability of real numbers (proof with nested intervals property)

Tags: real-analysis

I found the proof of uncountability of real numbers, but I have one question. Why can we not use the same logic to prove, that the set of natural numbers is also uncountable? So proof of uncountability of real numbers.

Proof: We will prove that the unit interval $I:=[0,1]$ is an uncountable set. This implies that the set $\mathbb R$ is an uncountable set. The proof is by contradiction. If we assume that $I$ is countable, then we can enumerate the set as $I:=\{x_1,x_2,x_3...x_n...\}$. We first select a closed subinterval $I_1$ of $I$ such that $x_1 \notin I_1$, then select a closed subinterval $I_2$ of $I$ that $x_2 \notin I_2$ and so on. In this way, we obtain nonempty closed intervals $$I_1\supseteq I_2 \supseteq...\supseteq I_n \supseteq...$$ such that $I_n \subseteq I$ and $x_n \notin I_n$ for all $n$. The Nested Intervals Property implies that there exists a point $\xi \in I_n$ for all $n$. Therefore $\xi \neq x_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$, so the enumeration of $I$ is not a complete listing of the elements of $I$, as claimed. Hence, $I$ is an uncountable set.

The question is, why can we use the same argument to prove that the set of natural numbers is also uncountable? Thank you for help!

Comment: You need closed intervals of *finite* length.

Comment: @DavidMitra I'm so stupid. Thank u!! Have a nice day!

Comment: @StinkingBishop I will do it, thank u!